# change gasLimit parameter into the genesis.json file on azure priavte blockchain

Tags: azure, blockchain, ethereum, azure-hub

I am trying to deploy a smart contract to an azure blockchain. 
The contract is deployed without errors but i can't submit transaction to the blockchain through this contract. 
I guess this is an issue with gasLimit, because when I use my private geth blockhain where I can set my gasLimit in the genesis.json file, my Dapp works perfectly and I can run my transaction. 
The gasLimit on azure is set up by microsoft on the genesis.json file and I would like to find a way to change it. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Comment: Can you add the actual error message and deployed contract to the question, as they are very relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Simple you cannot do that easily. Before deploying your ethereum network on Azure you have the option to select a custom genesis file, or go by the default one that they provide.. whenever you spin off the service, you will still have access to that file called genesis.json but unfortunately I've contacted microsoft several times for this exact issue and they were not able to help. I'll update you whenever I get anything new.